# Define range of value

Tags: java, math

I need to set an int variable in each iteration +-1, the range should be between 0-10. When i add 1 to 10 -> 0 when i add -1 to 0 -> 10. I know i need to go with modulo here but cannot find any solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Show the code you've tried. That's really important if you want help. Usually I'm at work when I answer questions and I don't really have the time to spend guessing at what someone may have tried. I'm therefore much more likely to answer questions that have code with them. Also, I think those who answer questions appreciate the effort made by the person asking - the only way to get good is to try to figure things out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to easy, but if you really want to use modulo, did you try;

```
    x = (x + y) % 11;
    if (x < 0) x += 11;
```

or for "ultimate readability" and probably still better performance just

```
    x = x + y;
    if (x < 0)  x += 11;
    if (x > 11) x -= 11;
```

Please note that the requirements locks y down to being -1 or 1.

Comment: `(0 + -1) % 11` is out of range

Comment: i was here : (x+(11+y))%11 is there easier way?

Comment: I missed the range of y being only -1 to 1, your way would indeed work, even if a bit hard to read.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the "ultimate readability" option for x = 0, y = 500 results in 489. Slightly off I would say.

Comment: @Mathias, the requirements say that y can only be -1 or +1.

Comment: Given your clarification I wish I could remove my down-vote, but it is locked unless you edit your answer.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Edited to reflect the requirements :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6516/discussion-between-joachim-isaksson-and-mathias)